# Flutter PATH setup doesn't work in M1 Macbook

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-ios

I have followed this [guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos) to setup Flutter in M1 Mac. I moved it to USERNAME/Developer/flutter directory and follow [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path) to update PATH. Though I have setup my PATH but it seems if I close the terminal and reopen it, it doesn't get the Flutter anymore. So it works once only and after reopening terminal I need to setup the PATH again as like as a new setup.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is weird and it shouldn't happen in my opinion. I have it setup in a similar way [here](https://github.com/Yash-Garg/dotfiles/blob/stable/macOS/.zshrc#L3).

Also make sure you have **zsh** set as the default shell or try adding the path export to the `.bash_profile` file.